# Advice and considerations for converting HTML4 to HTML5 website.

Tags: javascript, css, html, gimp

I have a website that I need to convert to HTML5. I need advice and whether it can truly be converted to an HTML5.

Please tell me, how I should start? Should I just start using HTML5 code in lieu of existing HTML4.
I will need to later add video content and a image scroller. Also if need be, should I redesign the site from scratch? I dont think this should be a problem.
Also the site is not friendly with form factors other than deskop/laptop.
It does not work well with mobile small display for which case HTML5 is anyways needed.

Do not hesitate or think too much. I need to know what you guys have in mind before I take a major step. I need to do this in under a month, I cannot afford to waste anymore time on it.

I have used gimp to make the icons for this website, but i dont think much of those icons will be needed with the new code.

Also, should I make a design prototype in gimp for my website. Later on I can add the css/html5. Do you think its worth the extra time or should I use one of the ready made templates?

Comment: "Please tell me, how I should start?" — Matter of opinion. "Should I just start using HTML5 code in lieu of existing HTML4. I will need to later add video content and a image scroller. " — Matter of opinion. "should I redesign the site from scratch?" — Matter of opinion. " It does not work well with mobile small display for which case HTML5 is anyways needed." — False assumption. "Also, should I make a design prototype in gimp for my website." — Matter of opinion.

Comment: Changing the doctype is the major part of the job since HTML5 is compatible with older versions. Then you can validate it on http://validator.w3.org/ to see if you have errors. Also try to change your divs for their new semantic versions if you can (header, footer, nav, section, article, aside ...)

Comment: Quentin I dont see your point. Yes, Im interested in your opinion.                                                                                                           Mehdi, thanks. Yes HTML5 is compatible with older version, but older versions cant upscale to newer standards... I think most web developers and even users are aware neither chrome nor firefox have rigid consistency in handling/rendering webpages correctly. The same thing is more profound on mobile devices. This is the very reason Im taking HTML5 seriously. And then you have videos vs flash(The feaces of the internet).

Comment: @pamfeuerS Quentin implies that your question is not suitable for stackoverflow, which is **not** a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use GIMP to design everything from scratch, follow the steps described here:

http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_migration.asp

they will guide you to convert your existing website to use HTML 5

Comment: That is a helpful link Mohamed. The reason I suggested gimp is because I can make a simpler template to which I could add the HTML5/CSS3. I dont know whether editing code will be any easier.  I was thinking if I could do a simpler design and then work on that things might get a bit more simpler and easier to manage. Later on I also plan to integrate and manage  the site and content using Django. What do you think, a simple redesign is a smarter choice or editing an obsolete template based on an older standard is a smarter??

Answer (score 1):

Yes any site can be converted in HTML5. It is simple process, first you have to change doctype from old to new which is very short doctype. Please change your doc type statement on top of site to following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Meta coding also another thing you need to change from old version to latest which is following.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

After changing your meta coding now see all div and change them to Semantics div. In past we used mostly div to separate part or to design our layout. Now try to see if some div have any specific meaning like header, footer, article, section and convert them accordingly. Only remaining div should for design purpose but all other who have specific meaning should be converted to tags which are provided by HTML5.
Now another thing need to be done is Nav, where ever you see navigation please put it in  tag as html5 uses this tag to specify list of links.
When you do all this there is possibility that old browser would not support so to bring support back use add Shiv a javascript that bring these special tags in previous version of html. Now change your css as all div you change require redefining tag instead of div in css too.

As for your part of Mobile version or sizing it is not of HTML5 but it is about CSS you have to use media queries in css to customise different styles for different size. Media query will let you know what size of display is and than you have to add styles and do changes some big parts break in linear format to give perfect view in Mobile and Menu be removed and a button is added.

Now add video and other media but remember that different video formats are supported by different browser so you have to provide multiple format to be used in html5 video. Also have to use for compatibility purpose old flash.
GIMP you can use if you want to redesign or change design of site otherwise for html5 I don't see its usage.